# .vrapperrc binding to fold current method/class in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin

By default they're bound to `Ctrl` + `Numpad_Minus` and `Ctrl` + `Numpad_Plus` .

But I want a `vrapper` binding , something like `:nnoremap ,, :ToggleFolding<cr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are default bindings `zo`,`zc` and `za` .